# comma in plot instead of years

Tags: r, plot

I have prices data set `Meerssen_prices` which I want to plot year-wise. However, the years appear as a decimal number in the plot. How can I get rid of that?

```
year    Wheat
1826    1.27
1827    1.26
1828    2.1
1829    2.2
1830    2.5
1831    3.5
1832    3.9
1833    2.6
1834    1.15
1835    1.15
1836    1.1
1837    1.15
1838    2.5
1839    2.1
1840    2.2
1841    2.24
1842    2.15
1843    2.1
1844    1.25
1845    2.2
1846    3.1
1847    3.1
1848    2.2
1849    2.1
1850    2.75
1851    2.6
1852    2.2
1853    2.16
1854    4.16
1855    4.25
1856    3.1
1857    2.17
1858    2.17
1859    2.18
1860    3.1
1861    3.2
1862    3.15
1863    2.2
1864    2.1
1865    2.1
1866    2.1
1867    3.25
```

Here is my code:

```
  span <- input_slider(0.2, 1, value = 0.75)

  Meerssen_Prices %>%
  ggvis(~year, ~ Wheat) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_smooths(span = span)
```

But the final,plot looks like that:
[image]

How can help me here with getting rid of these decimal commas?

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to stckoverflow. Please use `dput` to copy your data, so it will be easier for user to reproduce the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the year variable from numeric to integer.

```
Meerssen_Prices %>%
  mutate(year= as.integer(year)) %>%
  ggvis(~year, ~ Wheat) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_smooths(span = span)
```

Comment: It's yet an integer...it doesn't work, the solution is in the comment posted by @Deena

Comment: yes, Deena´s post works. I had to reload ggvis though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
library(ggvis)

  span <- input_slider(0.2, 1, value = 0.75)

  Meerssen_Prices %>%
  ggvis(~year, ~ Wheat) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_smooths(span = span) %>%
  add_axis("x", title="year",  format="####")
```